# runtime error '1004': method 'range' of object '_global' failed

Tags: vba, excel

[image]

Can Anyone help with this error? It actually works in one computer but not in others

```
Dim Rango As Range, FilaFin As Long
Dim i As Long, x As Object
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Sheet1.Select
FilaFin = Range("E6:E13").Offset(0, 4).End(xlDown).Row
Sheet1.Range("E6:E13").Copy
Sheet4.Select
FilaFin = Range("C1048576").End(xlUp).Row + 1
Range("C" & FilaFin).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, 
SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=True
FilaFin = Range("E18:E25").Offset(0, 4).End(xlDown).Row
```

Comment: Please don't put screenshots of code in as images. Put the relevant parts of the code inline as text, and describe exactly the error you are getting. Ideally, the error message is text in the body of the question. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: It's so hard to help with only one code line.

Comment: I'm sorry, I added a larger part of the code

Comment: Do the two computers run different versions of Excel?  You may want to try FilaFin = Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1

Comment: Change the line to `FilaFin = Cells(Cells.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row +1`

Answer (score 2):

**1048576** rows are only available for Excel-2007 onward.

**65536** rows are available for Excel-2003 and older version.

That's why

> It actually works in one computer but not in others

---

Hard coding your number of rows is a bad practice. Just make it dynamic:

`Range(Cells(Rows.Count, 3),Cells(Rows.Count, 3)).End(xlUp).Row`

`Rows.Count` returns total no. of rows irrespective of the version.

Comment: `Range(Cells(Rows.Count, 3),Cells(Rows.Count, 3))` can be shortened to just `Cells(Rows.Count, 3)`.